# UINavigationController not displaying the back button in Root Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, button, back

I have one navigation controller in my entire project. When I use a show segue to move to the next controller, the back button that is supposed to be in the title bar simply does not show up. I know that users have experienced this problem, but so far, no solution has worked.

Comment: The "back" arrow should show automatically. There is not enough info here to help you though. Can you show your storyboard (and the segue types) or create a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: Are you presenting the controller modally?

Comment: No. I'm using a normal show segue. There really isn't much to show that would help. Just a standard navigation controller and a root view controller.

Answer (score 0):

For each view controller you have to set the back bar button as like follow,

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction:)];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

In swift,

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back.png"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backAction:")

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: What would that look like in Swift?